foottracking for shoe tryon project
i am trying to download a library for setting up my own foot tracking and shoe model display operation for a shoe tryon webapp project but every time i get an address it does not work because it only displays the final destination fila rather than the library
example is given below:

mind-ar-js and aframe library
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.4.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mind-ar@1.2.5/dist/mindar-face-aframe.prod.js"></script>

They are the mindar and aframe library hosted in cdn. They are the only things you need to build

This above address claims to be open source but when I try to access the library through the given address it just gives me a 404 error
will appreciate if anyone can share a working url for a foot tracking library for using ar.js (either using the aframe option or the three.js option, i can use either)
Thanks

The links seem to be working: https://jsfiddle.net/Lzgb5avu/1/ no 404s in the console, and you can see objects from both files. Not sure if either arjs or mindar support feet tracking, i'd check out this repo here https://github.com/topics/foot-tracking

thnx piotr, will chk ur suggestion asap and get back

repository looks spot on, hv uploaded it on server and demo works alright, now attempting to create our own index file... will keep u posted

Yayyyy got it working fantastic!!!

Now going to try tweaking InShaAllah
